# When and why is it justifiable to interchange the Re/Im part?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis

I've found a post similar to this one regarding the complexification of the integral, but the question I am looking for was not answered. I was looking for rigorous reasoning using analysis for what proceedes.

Why are we allowed to say

$$\int e^x \cos{x}\ \mathrm{d}x := \mathrm{Re}\left(\int e^x \cdot e^{ix}\right) \ \mathrm{d}x$$

Why is it justifiable to interchange the real part of $e^{ix}$ and the integral? Are there certain circumstances where we cannot interchange the Re/Im part of these functions? Or is it always justified? Just looking for some clarification on the latter. Thank you!!

Comment: The crux of the technique used in your question is not so much about swapping real part with integral (that happens by definition of integral of a complex valued function of a real variable). The crux is that the integral of $e^{ax} $ is $\frac{e^{ax}} {a} +c$ for all non-zero complex numbers $a$. The technique assumes this for free and you should prove it directly by differentiating $e^{ax} $.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $f$ and $g$ are real-valued functions on the reals, then 
$$
\int (f(x) + i g(x)) dx  = \int f(x)~ dx + i \int g(x)) dx,
$$
so that 
$$
Re\left(\int (f(x) + i g(x)) dx\right)  = Re \left( \int f(x)~ dx + i \int g(x) dx \right) = \int f(x)~ dx.
$$
Why? Because each of the integrals on the right is a real number, so the right-hand side is of the for $V + i W$, where $V$ and $W$ are real; the real part of this is just $V$, which is what's on the far right.

Apply this idea to $f(x) = e^x cos(x)$ and $g(x) =e^x \sin x$ to get the result you cited.

Comment: Well...they need to be integrable. :)

Comment: This is only true if we’re integrating along a horizontal line, of course; otherwise there will be an imaginary part to the dx.

Comment: Haha, alright!!

Comment: @BobJones: that's why I said "if $f$ and $g$ are real-valued functions **on the reals**"; integrating with a variable $x$ that moves off the reals doesn't even make sense.

Comment: @JohnHughes I agree that you answered the question completely and correctly. My comment was not a criticism of your answer, but a throwaway note on a technical flaw in the original question. Because the equation he wrote is false if you integrate x straight up the imaginary axis, for example.

Comment: Ah...I see your point now; let's hope that OP sees it as well. :)